# How to make my Admob Banner Ad Unit ID work?

Tags: admob, ads, banner, banner-ads

The banner Id that provided by Admob didn't return any ad.

also the test ad unit ID that given by this link:
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner
didn't return any ad.

on other hand 
the following Banner ID : works very well.

> ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111

so where is the problem ??

Comment: The problem is in your code somewhere. You should show what you have tried, and the exact error you get.

Comment: What is logs your getting for error.

Comment: there is no error but no ad banner is displayed.